# Unhelping error message

Tags: php, sql

What the flippedy hell is wrong with that error, and where does it come from ?

[image: error]

I'm in charge of renovating a website and the page was covered in errors because of the use of `mysql_connect`, so I switched to `mysqli_connect` and got this error in the process.

EDIT: Here's the code of "mysql.php":

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");

@session_start();
?>
```

(The session start is here because hte file is called at the start of every page. The informations in "..." has obviously been modified)

Comment: If you downvote a question, thank you for saying why. It doesn't help otherwise.

Comment: Can you please show us the code

Comment: Please provide code, we need the error AND the code to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the mysqli_connect. Question answered.

However to trouble shoot your problem(what you are acutally asking) try the following steps:

- if you make a blank php page and connect to the database, does it also give errors?
- Is the database server up and running?
- Is the database corrupted?
- is there a backup database?
- Is mysqli even installed on that server?
- What's the PHP version? Does it support mysqli?
- Did all mysql_real_escape_string get transformed to the mysqli variant?

Comment: The blank page gives the exact same result and the database is OK since the other site using it has no problem. The only difference between the two connection codes is that one runs on WAMP, the other on LAMP.

Comment: well did you run all the steps I listed above? Especially the mysqli one? run a phpinfo() for it.